# Possibility to print via printer dot matrix with PHP

Tags: php, printing, barcode, dot-matrix

Is there any possibility so we can print bill with printer dot/jet matrix in PHP? And also, can PHP detect for barcode reader ? or just simple method, I only provide input text then if I scan with barcode reader, directly fill to input text automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you could use jzebra plugin (https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) which detects all installed printers and provides escp javascript methods to send hexadecimal esc commands along with the text you want to print, while the actual printing is performed by a java applet.